# @ResponseBody and Spring rest services

Tags: json, spring, rest

I am new to spring rest services, I am little confused. If I have a Ajax request which needs JSON response then I added @ResponseBody annotation to my method and it gives me JSON of object.

However if I have to make a restful service then even I have to do the same. Was i creating a restful for ajax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

@ResponseBody – Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body. (java doc see more information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-responsebody))

So all it stats is that the method return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name)

The presentation of the result within the body will be affected from few parameters.
I recommend reading the following [section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-content-negotiation) about Content Negotiation:

Spring will use is own Heuristics to figure out the requested response presentation:

The doc's summarize this in the following paragraph:

> The available options are to check the file extension in the request
>   URI, the "Accept" header, a request parameter, as well as to fall back
>   on a default content type. By default, file extension in the request
>   URI is checked first and the "Accept" header is checked next.

You can use @RequestMapping to specify accept header.

`<mvc:annotation-driven>` element has a content-negotiation-manager attribute.
By default it will work with Jackson 2 in version 4, so all you need is to add the following to your classpath

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

On the client side you can consume the result with Ajax or using a direct url call.
The client side technology makes no different as long as it request the right content type.
If you get error 406 – your content type definition is conflicting with your request

You can look at the following example [here](https://github.com/ramanh3/rest-json.git)

Comment: If you are down-voting my answer at least specify way you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

look you need to understand what is restful webservices. restful webservices is a Methodology in which all available http methods are mapped to CURD( Create Update Read Delete )

```
Operation   SQL     HTTP    
Create      INSERT  POST    
Read        SELECT  GET 
Update      UPDATE  PUT 
Delete      DELETE  DELETE
```

so it is called restful webservice .if you are not following this strategy then its not.

Comment: hmmm its not mythology where gods fought wars. Its Methodology. Re-edit It. :)